# Declaration of ... must be compatible with

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm  using this Yii2 plugin for my user model

https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

In my `main.php` i have this.

```
 'user' => [
     'class' => Da\User\Module::class,
     'enableEmailConfirmation' => true,
      'classMap' => [
           'User' => 'app\models\user\Model\User',
           'SocialNetworkAccount' => 'app\models\user\Model\SocialNetworkAccount',
       ],
```

then in the directory `models/user/Model` i have this

```
namespace app\models\user\Model;
use Yii;
use app\models\user\Model\User;
use Da\User\Model\SocialNetworkAccount as BaseClass;

class SocialNetworkAccount extends BaseClass
{
 public function connect(User $user)
    {
        return $this->updateAttributes(
            [
                'username' => null,
                'firstname' =>  $user->firstname,
                'lastname' =>  $user->lastname,
                'email' => null,
                'code' => null,
                'user_id' => $user->id,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

but when i go to my login page i get this error

`Declaration of app\models\user\Model\SocialNetworkAccount::connect(app\models\user\Model\User $user) must be compatible with Da\User\Model\SocialNetworkAccount::connect(Da\User\Model\User $user)`

i tried following the tutorial here to override classes, but no luck

https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/enhancing-and-overriding/overriding-classes/

what am i doing wrong here? thanks

**UPDATE:**

i tried this

```
public function connect(\Da\User\Model\User $user)
```

don't get the error anymore, but now i noticed it doesn't add firstname and lastname

in my user model rules i have this

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            [['email', 'firstname', 'lastname'], 'safe'],
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you've described it looks like usuario is using DI container to create the `User` class instance when calling the `connect()` method.

When overriding it you have to follow the rule that **preconditions cannot be strengthened in a subtype.** That means that you can't typehint the parametr with the subclass of what the original method uses as its parametr. Your connect method definition must look like what you've posted in your question:

```php
public function connect(\Da\User\Model\User $user)
```

But because of that, the dependency injector is creating an instance of `Da\User\Model\User` when calling `connect()` method. So, what you've missed is setting the DI container to create instance of `app\models\user\Model\User` whenever it's supposed to create instance of `Da\User\Model\User` like this:

```php
'container' => [
    'definitions' => [
        Da\User\Model\User::class => app\models\user\Model\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Of course, for this to work your `app\models\user\Model\User` class must extend the `Da\User\Model\User` class.

There is a complete example how to override usuario's User model in [usuario's documentation](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/enhancing-and-overriding/how-to-enhance-a-user-model/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm actually trying to add firstname and lastname to the social connect page, like here.  but can't seem to find the solution anywhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68375873/yii2-usuario-custom-fields-in-social-connect-page. also do i put the `container definitions` in the main.php? sorry new to yii2

Comment: and yes, i did extend the user model too (`Da\User\Model\User`)

Comment: Yes you can put it in main.php config. You can find more info about configuration here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations#application-configurations

Comment: getting the same error after i added the container :(

Comment: `public function connect(\Da\User\Model\User $user)` doesn't give me errors, but the user table is not updated with `firstname` and `lastname`